# Drop down form dissapearing when using AJAX to get PHP file to retrieve data from MySQL db

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Im using AJAX to make a php file get data from a MySQL database and populating it in a drop down depending on the users first choice drop down. Everything is working fine and the second drop down is populated correctly.

The issue I am having is when selecting an option from the second drop down the whole second drop down just disappears on selection and I cant work out why.

The working example can be found [HERE](http://www.projector-screen-material.co.uk/blah/).

### The Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="width" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a Width:</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">
    <form>
    <select name="length" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
    <option value="">Step 2</option>
    </select>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### The PHP file - getuser.php

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysql_connect('cust-mysql-123-17','products','abc123','products');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));
  }

mysql_select_db("products",$con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM deepblack WHERE width = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);


echo "<form>
<select name=\"length\" onchange=\"showUser(this.value)\">
    <option value=\"\">Select a Length</option>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value=\"\">". $row['length'] ."</option>";
        }
echo"
    </select>
    </form>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Could anyone please help me to why it just disappears?

The end result that I need is the user selects a width, this then populates the second drop down with available lengths. From the the second drop down the user selects a length to purchase. So the whole second drop down I plan on being a form which sends the selection to PayPal or another merchant. If anyone knows a better way of doing this also please say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second Drop down has `Value=""`

```
<select onchange="showUser(this.value)" name="length">
<option value="">Select a Length</option>
<option value="">5</option>
<option value="">10</option>
</select>
```

When you select it, it calls the JS and execute this condition:

```
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 

....
```

which overwrite the DIV with `ID=txtHINT`

**If you want to fix it:** Make sure in this line

```
        echo "<option value=\"\">". $row['length'] ."</option>";
```

the value isn't empty, or change the JS.

Comment: thanks, so I just need to remove the onchange and value attributes?